# Quartz.Net - Cron Schedule Builder not working after 12/31/2020

Tags: c#, asp.net, cron, quartz.net

I'm trying to get a cron job working in Quartz.net that has suddenly started acting up and not running at all. It was working fine through December 31st, 2019 but as of 2020 has simply stopped running.

```
public static async Task StartScheduledTasksAsync()
    {

            // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory 
            IScheduler scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

            // and start it off
            await scheduler.Start();

            // define the job and tie it to our LogPendingRequests class
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SendReports>()
                .WithIdentity("job", "group")
                .Build();

            // Trigger the job to run now, and then daily at 8 AM EST.
            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger", "group")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(8, 0).InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")))
                .Build();

        // define the job and tie it to our SetAllEquipmentMaintenanceStatus class
        IJobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.Create<SetAllEquipmentMaintenanceStatus>()
            .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .Build();

        // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 24 hours
        ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
            .WithIntervalInHours(24)
            .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
    }
```

Unfortunately it seems as though the job SetAllEquipmentMaintenanceStatus runs just fine on a schedule every 24 hours but the cron job SendReports does not want to run. I have no idea why. When I switch the SendReports job to the other trigger and the SetAllEquipmentMaintenanceStatus to the cron job trigger, the SendReports job works as expected but the SetAllEquipmentMaintenanceStatus does not run, so I know it's the trigger but I have no idea how to fix it.

I have made no coding changes except a minor patch on December 4, 2019. Aside from that no new code was merged in, so I'm fairly sure this was some change beyond my control. Have there been any updates to Quartz that might cause this issue?

I'm going to try updating the NuGet package and check back on this question. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Quick comment - Quartz.net is updated to the latest stable release which is 3.0.7. Updating the version will not fix this apparently.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check what dates your trigger will run on is to use [TriggerUtils](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/TriggerUtils.cs). With following code:

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger", "group")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(8, 0).InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")))
    .Build();

var fireTimes = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimesBetween(
    (IOperableTrigger) trigger,
    cal: null,
    from: new DateTimeOffset(2019, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero),
    to: new DateTimeOffset(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero));
```

I get (UTC times):

```
31.12.2019 13.00.00 +00:00
1.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
2.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
3.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
4.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
5.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
6.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
7.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
8.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
9.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
10.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
11.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
12.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
13.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
14.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
15.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
16.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
17.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
18.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
19.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
20.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
21.1.2020 13.00.00 +00:00
.... the list goes on ...
```

So from Quartz's viewpoint, the trigger is valid and should fire. A pitfall that could cause problems is to have a constructor in job that could throw exceptions, this would show job as no-op. Have you tried enabling more logging to verify that it's Quartz not processing the job?

Comment: I have not. Where does that log to? This is a production system so I cannot live debug it or read the console. I could try it in our test environment.

Comment: Please try in another environment. Based on schedule the job should run. Quartz automatically detects logging via liblog, so log4net, serilog etc should work. I highly recommend logging at least error level in production (for every application).